# LiipImagineBundle not working on production with nginx

Tags: php, nginx, symfony5, liipimaginebundle

I use LiipImagineBundle 2.3.1 on Symfony 5.2 but id doesn't create cached files on production environment, throwing a 404. It works just fine on dev.

If I run `php bin/console liip:imagine:cache:resolve image.jpg --filter=filter_name` it does create the image so I guess the problem is related to nginx.

nginx version is 1.18.0
PHP version is 7.4.3

**liip_imagine.yaml:**

```
liip_imagine:

    driver: "gd"

    resolvers:    
      default:    
        web_path: ~   

    filter_sets:    
      cache: ~    
      avatar:    
        quality: 75   
        filters:
             thumbnail: { size: [200, 200], mode: outbound }
```

**nginx config:**

```
server {
    server_name default_server;
    root /var/www/mysite/public;
   
    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewrite_framework_symfony;
    }

    location @rewrite_framework_symfony {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }
    
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 365d;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }    
}
```

Does somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the issue.

/media/cache got the permissions for root and not for www-data, the nginx user.

```
$ chown -R www-data:www-data media/cache/
```